# JMeter- Validating if REST response is indeed in JSON format

Tags: jmeter

I am starting out so excuse my naive question. I researched on how to test if REST response is indeed is JSON/ or in JSON format.  I get two options either to use the plugin JSON Path Assertion or regular expression.  But I am not sure how to use the plugin to validate if the response is in JSON format.  I do not want to test any specifics of the results. How can I do it in JMeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Beanshell Post Processor:**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

try
{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    //valid json
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // not a valid json
}
```

You might need [this jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgjsonjar.htm) in the lib folder. You migt not need this if you already have jmeter plugins for json path extractor etc.

**JSON Path Extractor:**

If the response is not in the valid json format, then the value of `json` will be `NOT_JSON`. Otherwise it will have the json doc as string.

[image]